# NHibernate Oracle mapping problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, oracle10g

Before stating the problem, please look at the code

Database(Oracle) SQL:

```
create table test_tab(
 id number,
 Name varchar2(50)
);
```

Corresponding Class in C#:

```
public class TestTable
    {
        private long id;
        public virtual long Id {
            get {
                return id;
            }
            set {
                id = value;
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The mapping file for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DataTransfer" namespace="DataTransfer">
  <class name="DataTransfer.Models.TestTable, DataTransfer" table="TEST_TAB">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">
          seq_test
        </param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="NAME" type="string" not-null="false"/> 
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> The "TestTable" class is inside the
>   Models folder under DataTransfer project

hibernate configuration figuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=xe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=hr;Unicode=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <!-- mapping files -->
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my DataAccessLayer Code;

```
public void AddToTestTable(Test_Tab user)
        {
            using (ISession session = GetSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Save(user);
                        session.Flush();
                    }
                    catch (NHibernate.HibernateException)
                    {
                        tx.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is when I insert any value to the database(using simple ASP.NET form) nothing happens(even no exceptions!). But it worked perfectly when i did not use "Models" folder for TestTable Class and "Mappings" folder for mapping files. Please help me out.

Comment: How do you insert / add an entity to the DB ? Can you show some code please ?
Do you flush the session for instance ? Or, how did you confiugre the flushmode ?

Comment: Oops!!!!!!!! I found my problem!!

Comment: Mr Flint, if you found the solution, you should create an "Answer" and accept it, so that future generations will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `.hbm.xml` mapping file is embedded as a resource in the assembly `DataTransfer`.

Comment: When the mapping is not embedded as a resource, NH will throw an exception since it will treat the class as a 'non persitent' class.  In other words: it will throw an exception since it does not know how to persist the entity.